# Sorting a Refinement List in Algolia Using Integers in Title as Integers, not Varchar

Tags: javascript, algolia

I have a set of values in an Algolia **refinement list** that are being displayed this way when I `sortBy: ['name:asc']`:

[image]

How might I get this to display in the expected format:

```
Grade 1
Grade 2
Grade 3
Grade 4
...
Grade 11
Grade 12
```

(Even better if I could get 'Kindergarten' first before all other values!)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.menu({
        container: '#grade_menu',
        attribute: 'grades_JSON.long',
        sortBy: ['name:asc'],
        limit: 13,
        cssClasses: {
            showMore: 'btn-dark',
            count: 'tiny-text',
        },
        templates: {
            item: `
                <li class="nav-item pl-0 ml-0">
                <a class="nav-link" href="@{{slug}}">
                <span class="@{{cssClasses.label}}">@{{label}}</span>
                <span class="@{{cssClasses.count}}">
                @{{#helpers.formatNumber}}@{{count}}@{{/helpers.formatNumber}}
                </span>
                </a>
                </li>
            `,
        },
     })
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your widget options, [`sortBy`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/refinement-list/js/#widget-param-sortby) can be given a function that behaves like [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Which means you could have something like:

```
function sortGrades(a, b) {
  if (a.name == "Kindergarten") {
    return -1;
  } else if (b.name == "Kindergarten") {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return Number(a.name.match(/[0-9]+/)[0]) - Number(b.name.match(/[0-9]+/)[0]);
  }
}

search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.menu({
        // ...
        sortBy: sortGrades,
        // ...
     })
);
```

`"Kindergarten"` will always be sorted first, while other values will be sorted depending on the number within the facet name.

Comment: ahah my pleasure @SheldonScott :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but thought I'd share what I used to sort some weirdly named age groups within a [refinementList](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/refinement-list/js/#widget-param-sortby) widget.

```
function sortAges(a, b) {
  var ordering = {},
      sortOrder = ['0 - 6 months','0 - 1','2 - 5','6 - 8','9 - 11','12 - 17','18+','0-19','All ages'];
      
  for (var i=0; i<sortOrder.length; i++)
      ordering[sortOrder[i]] = i;

  return (ordering[a.name] - ordering[b.name]) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
}
```

for:

```
instantsearch.widgets.refinementList({
    container: '#ages-list',
    attribute: 'ages',
    sortBy: sortAges
}),
```